# Microphone active low pass filter doesn't work

Tags: amplifier, microphone, low-pass, active-filter

I am trying to make an active low pass filter for my school project. I need to design a filter with 2000 Hz cut off freq and 20-25 gain. I tried to use TI filter design tool and analog devices filter tool without success.I will add some of circuit I tried.
[image]
[image]

I mostly lost my audio signal in the input the op amp. Also I completely lost signal in the output of the op amp.

The circuit doesn't show it, but I am connecting my electret microphone's positive leg to input of the circuit and negative leg to ground.

Some of my research tells me use buffer between microphone and op amp because there is an impadance difference. But I don't understand that. If anyone knows this kind of circuits and how to connect microphone into the circuit please help me. Thanks.

Also I am adding screenshots from audocity program that can record auio.

[image: from output of the microphone]

[image: from output of the op amp.]

As you can see my test voice dissapear in the output of the opamp.

Comment: When you are required to have a gain of 20...25 none of the shown circuits can do this (without an extra gain stage)! More than that, all the passive elements are calculated for an IDEAL input voltage source (zero source impedance).

Comment: doesn't need to be gain ration in the first circuit's (R4+R3)/3 ?

Comment: Also Lvw do you have any advice for me to complete this circuit. Gain can be change It doesnt matter it is x18,20 or 25. I need to see this s amplifing and filtering.

Comment: The fixed voltage gain for the Sallen-Key filter must be pretty low (mostly below "3"). Recommemdation (if you are allowed to use two opamps): Sallen-Key structure with unity gain (classical design based on TI filter tool) and a following gain stage as wanted/required.

Comment: @BatuhanYavaşoğlu In addition to what LvW tells you about the typical Sallen-Key filter gain (there are actually ***many*** more than most people realize, but he is nail-on regarding the usual cases), you need to provide the supply needs for the electret microphone, itself. Since electret microphones come in a variety of forms, these days, and there is NOT a one-size fits all for them, it would help to know exactly which electret you have.